# Why is this SQL Server question "primarily opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based

This question ([Dynamically reorder column values in a SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659579/)) asks about a SQL approach to dynamic reordering of values in a SQL column. After I answered the question with some SQL code, it was closed as "opinion-based":

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

Why is this question opinion-based?

After editing, the question doesn't ask for an opinion. And the only answer (mine) to this question is code-based. Looking at this from the perspective of whether it will help future viewers with a question about dynamic reordering in SQL column values, I'm pretty sure that it will.

Comment: *"What is the best approach"* is an opinion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the question asks for a "good" approach, not the "best" approach .

Comment: The OP didn't ask for "the best approach" but for "a good approach". I believe editing that to change it into "How to..." would probably be enough to fix the question.

Comment: It does *now*, the first revision didn't.

Comment: I now see they originally asked for "the best approach", and you edited into "a good approach". Still not ideal wording, but a further edit could be all that it's needed. Many of the CVs may have been casted on earlier revisions, which were poorer.

Comment: @yivi, Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the question now to be "How should I...". Hopefully it will be reopened.

Comment: It still lacks an attempt; SO isn't a query writing service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, 3 of the 5 close votes were cast after I edited the question from "best approach" to "good approach". As yivi says, that was still not ideal wording. But it feels like the 3 later close votes were just dog-piling.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, this is about the close reason (opinion-based). Maybe there should be another close reason such as "SO isn't a code-writing service"?

Comment: Agree or disagree with the closure, that's fine. But please, do not ascribe motives ("dog-piling") on other users' votes unless you are privy to their thoughts. Whatever we believe, the more likely scenario is that they actually thought the question was worth closing.

Comment: Also some of the close votes may have been for other reasons but the majority reason is what will get shown to users.

Comment: @jivi, I didn't ascribe a motive - I just said what it felt like to me. If the community says we should be pedantic about the finer details of a question's wording, then we should also be pedantic about the finer details of a comment's wording :-)

Comment: @RoadWarrior "*I didn't ascribe a motive - I just said what it felt like to me.*" that's ascribing a motive.

Comment: @VLAZ, ascribe is defined as "to regard as arising from", "to regard as belonging to", "to credit or assign". I talked about my feelings, not about the reality - which neither you nor I know.

Comment: Neither best nor good mean anything in particular. The question is also a frequently asked duplicate. Also that's obviously so. Also it shows no research effort. It has no MRE. The question & its answer are just cluttering up the site. Also, given, all that, some people may just be trying to get it closed as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first revision of the question asked for *"the best approach for..."*, which certainly stinks to "opinion based".

Since that original revision some additional edits were performed, up to changing that phrase to *"what's a good approach"*, which is better but still not ideal, and some other users might have found objectionable.

We can't see **when** was each of the close votes casted, but it's likely that only the last vote was casted after the edit that changed "best" -> "good".

Changing that question to a clearer "How do I do X" makes it good enough, in my eyes, and I believe it could be reopened.

I'll leave it up to tag experts to judge if it's worth reopening it.

Comment: Still a *"give me the codes"* type question with no research effort displayed or attempts shown

Comment: If it's a "how to" question, as long as it is adequately scoped, it doesn't necessarily needs to provide code.

Comment: @yivi, I was watching the question closely. 3 of the 5 close votes came after my edit from "best" to "good".

Comment: So they still thought the edit was not good enough, apparently. Hopefully your last edit will make some other users cast reopen votes. It's a much improved version, IMO.

Comment: @RoadWarrior Well, your question and this answer seem to be working! I just cast a re-open vote, and it's now on a count of 3. 

Comment: @charlietfl no research/no attempt is reason for a downvote not for a close vote. (note that voting on such "how-to" questions usually is more upvote for  "I know the answer"/"that's fun exercise" and downvote for "boring"/"approach is so awkward that its not even trollable")